# How to change templates values in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

First of all i apologize for my english, im not a native speaker.

I'm working on a "theme picker" for my app, made an "Button Template" i don't really know if its call that way but at least in the docs says that. Works fine, all the buttons have the same properties

Now i want to change the "backgroud_color" from this "template" when i click a button (in a theme picker screen)

As it is outside the ScreenManager I can't find a way to manipulate it from it, i try with ListProperty in diferent places but nothing seems to work and couldn't find any answer in google
Made a simple new GUI to represent what i want to do

```
main.py

from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty,ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Screen3(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

```
test.kv

<Button>:
    color: 1,1,1,1
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: [1, 0.275, 0.333, 1] #Red
    #background_color: [0, 0, 1, 1] #Next Color

<ScreenManager>:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Screen3:

<Screen1>:
    name: "Screen1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Label:
            text: "Test"
        Button:
            text:"Next Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen2'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            Button:
                text:"ChangeColor1"
            Button:
                text:"ChangeColor2"

<Screen2>:
    name: "Screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Label:
            text: "Test2"
        Button:
            text:"Next Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen3'
        

<Screen3>:
    name: "Screen3"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Label:
            text: "Test3"
        Button:
            text:"Next Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen1'
```

Hope someone can help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a kivy `Property` by defining that `Property` in the `App`, and referencing it in the `kv`. In your `App`, just define the `Property` like this:

```
class TestApp(App):
    bg_color = ListProperty([1, 0.275, 0.333, 1])
```

Then access that `bg_color` in the kv:

```
<Button>:
    color: 1,1,1,1
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: app.bg_color  # reference the bg_color Property of the App

<ScreenManager>:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Screen3:

<Screen1>:
    name: "Screen1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Label:
            text: "Test"
        Button:
            text:"Next Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen2'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            Button:
                text:"ChangeColor1"
                on_release: app.bg_color = [0, 0, 1, 1]  # adjust the bg_color Property of the App
            Button:
                text:"ChangeColor2"
                on_release: app.bg_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]  # adjust the bg_color Property of the App

<Screen2>:
    name: "Screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Label:
            text: "Test2"
        Button:
            text:"Next Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen3'
        

<Screen3>:
    name: "Screen3"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Label:
            text: "Test3"
        Button:
            text:"Next Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen1'
```

In the above `kv` code, the `bg_color` Property is referenced in the `<Button>` rule and is modified by the `ChangeColor` Buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works awesome! 

I will leave what i do to add more colors if someone ends up in this post and need to know it.
 all i have to do was create more ListProperties in the app class
class TestApp(App):
    bg_color = ListProperty([1, 0.275, 0.333, 1])
    color2 = ListProperty([0, 0, 1, 1])

and in the kv file write "on_release: app.bg_color = app.color2" without even needing a function, also works for labels.

Thanks again for the response